# How to use RabbitMQ with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, rabbitmq

I am trying to publish text messages to a RabbitMQ's queue. Since I am new to Angular so I don't know how can I do that.

The name of the queue is 'messages'. How can I do this?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: Reference this GitHub project this will really help you to have the better understanding of STOMP implementation. Link: https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-websocket-chat-demo

Answer (score 3):

rabbitmq does not implement the `http` protocol by default.

you can use the [web-stomp](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) plugin. In this way you can use java script directly.